# How do I extract building elevation values from Multipatch GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d

I have a GDB Multipatch Buildings layer that I open with ArcScene or ArcGlobe.
I want to extract building elevation values, but this is not stored in the attribute table. I can run a "Add Z Information", but I was wondering if someone can guide me on how to extract it with FME.

Comment: There are multiple ways to extract coordinate data from geometries.  Please edit the question to specify your programming language preference.